# How can I select (project) only one dimension of a tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 2D tensor in TensorFlow, and I want to select only 1D of it.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice). Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

initial = tf.truncated_normal([2,3], mean=100.0, stddev = 10.0)
slice1 = tf.slice(initial, [0,0], [1,-1])
slice2 = tf.slice(initial, [0,0], [-1, 1])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    x,y,z = sess.run([initial, slice1, slice2])
    print "original"
    print x
    print "slice1"
    print y
    print "slice2"
    print z
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
original
[[  94.17047119   90.71355438   90.06797791]
 [  99.81169891   99.91291809  106.17702484]]
slice1
[[ 94.17047119  90.71355438  90.06797791]]
slice2
[[ 94.17047119]
 [ 99.81169891]]
```

In this example, `slice` accepts three arguments. In order, they are:

- `input`: A Tensor of `N` dimensions `[d1, ..., dN]` holding the data that you want to slice from. In our case, it is a 2D Tensor of `[heigth, width]`.
- `begin`: A list of length `N`, specifying the starting position of your slide. You can see it intuitively as the accessor index, as you would do in [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html). Therefore, **it denotes a scalar element of your tensor**. In our case, `[0,0]` would point to the number in the "upper, left"-most position.
- `size`: Also a list of length `N`, specifies the size of the output tensor, starting at `begin` and taking the corresponding number of elements per dimension. In our example, it can contain any number between `[0,0]` and  `[heigth,width]`, but if it contains any zeros it will cause slice to return an empty tensor. Also, you can't overrun the actual size of your input tensor (for instance, if you have 3 elements and you start at the second, you can only have 1 or 2, but not 3).

Also note that both the `begin` and `size` magnitudes are resolved when building the graph. In both cases you can use `-1` as equivalent to the maximal size of that dimension (as generally in python).

Comment: Can you please explain what the exact role of the constants (e.g. `[0,0]`) are, and how you derived them?

Comment: yes, I'll edit my question. In any case I would recommend to check the API, especially if intending to work with more than 2D tensors

Answer (score 1):

just for completeness, if you want to select the "full" dimension and not actually just a slice of it, then this seems easier and also reduces the tensor by one dimension:

```
import tensorflow as tf

initial = tf.truncated_normal([2,3], mean=100.0, stddev = 10.0)
slice1 = initial[0]
slice2 = initial[:, 0]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    x,y,z = sess.run([initial, slice1, slice2])
    print("original")
    print(x)
    print("slice1")
    print(y)
    print("slice2")
    print(z)
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
original
[[  94.17047119   90.71355438   90.06797791]
 [  99.81169891   99.91291809  106.17702484]]
slice1
[ 94.17047119  90.71355438  90.06797791]
slice2
[ 94.17047119 99.81169891]
```

Comment: Of course, indexing is more elegant. Thanks for bringing it up!